# Smallest Delay Possible in a really dumb RF communication

Tags: rf, wireless

I want to use RF to do a really simple switch over wireless. My design is really simple: a pair of transmitter and receiver, with transmitter sending energy on certain frequency (energy high enough to distinguish from the noise), and receiver detects if there is enough energy on the frequency. I only need to transmit 1 bit of data in my case (energy exists on certain frequency for 1, otherwise 0).
The problem is that I need to transmit it really really fast (in the level of micro seconds), that is to say, from transmitter starts to receive a high voltage and begins sending signal, until the receiver detects the signal and outputs a high voltage (here signal is just energy on a certain frequency), the delay needs to be as small as possible.
I know there is a booting delay on the transmitter side when it gets the sending command (time between standby state until transmitter reaches its maximum sending power state), and there is a detection delay on the receiver side (time between the signal actually reaches the receiver and the receiver outputs a high voltage). I want to know how long are these delays, and what is the smallest possible delay I can get.

Edit:
Here is the background of this problem: I am currently doing a research program, which involves several devices in the space (e.g. in a room), and each of them is equipped with a RF transmitter and receiver. I want to trigger an operation on all of these devices simultaneously (within short time), and the initial triggering command can be sent by any of the devices. Each device is set to repeat the single tone (energy on certain frequency) once it receives it, so other devices that are out of range can eventually get the signal.
Current I am using a pair of OOK RF 433Mhz transmitter and receiver ([XCSOURCE](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00V4ISS38/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)), the result is not good enough, the latency is around 30~40us.

Comment: Not to sound discouraging but 1) You will probably be violating FCC rules by doing this. UWB is a-kin to what you describe but it operates on nW power levels. 2) There is EMI from various sources that will cause this switch to turn on and off at seemingly random times.

Comment: It seems like you could probably do this (if either your noise level was always low enough (unlikely) or if your transmitter was powerful enough (illegal) or if your transmitter was close enough to your receiver (pointless)) just by having a receiver that would detect a signal over a preset threshold. This is fairly easy analog circuit to make AFAIK, and the delay time would I guess be very small, on the order of microseconds or nano seconds depending on your design. The big question, of course, is why you would want to do this?

Comment: This problem is underspecified.  Taken literally and without imagination it is unlikely that you can accomplish this in a way that is legal, reliable and affordable.  What problem are you *really* trying to solve?  If you want fast response, you need high bandwidth and to get that you generally need high frequency.  At a certain point, *directivity* and *shielding* may start to be your primary defense against interference.  Follow where that points and you move through the microwave bands, possibly to end up with a laser.

Comment: Moving the mileposts way out there with an edit is not very nice.  You do not indicate how big the room is or what the regulatory environment is.  You have not made a case for why you cannot blanket the whole 'room' with multiple transmitters so no repeating is required.  You have not indicated why the timing needs to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Latency can be estimated by the distance travelled by the speed of light of 300 m/μs with the rise time of the Rx bandwidth which may include RF and IF filters necessary to suppress adjacent carrier signals.  Where rise time = 1/3 of 1/f (f = filter Bandwidth) This requires design of simple AM Rx with no PLL.

The next delay is the AGC circuit unless a predetermined threshold for a fixed loss is defined or no AGC is used.

Latency is a tradeoff for signal selectivity or BW.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I will use a pre-defined threshold for the AGC circuit.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a modulated signal you can easily achieve what you want using standard technology.

The data rates for regular WiFi systems can be over 10Mbps that would be a 100ns timing resolution.  I would see if there are some older low level modulator ICs that would do what you need.

Otherwise a normal analogue video signal has a bandwidth of a few MHz and should be able to take almost arbitrary signals if you have some background signals that will keep the ALC and AGC circuits working.  You could probably use 10% and 90% duty cycles at 100kHz to get a 10us response time.

**EDIT:**
OP wanted responses in microseconds, let us say 2us that means a bandwidth of 1MHz.  I think Dimitry and OP have not tried to use the ideas to gain inspiration.  If I offered a raw 34Mbps data path that would have been sloppy of me but a symbol rate of 1M/s is plenty of bandwidth since it includes all the overhead and could handle simple unstructured ON-OFF data at an even higher rate.

After the edit to the OP question the limitations have been made near impossible to achieve without having some other requirements relaxed. Having to support multiple interfering devices will not be practical with any other technique than basic AM or ASK and getting the desired response times will be hard because AGC/ALC circuits will not be able to respond fast enough.

http://80211notes.blogspot.fi/2013/08/wi-fi-80211-phy-data-rates.html

Comment: You can't really evaluate delays like that. It's like saying "half a million people are born in country X each year, so pregnancy there only lasts 1 minute".

Comment: WiFi transmits multiple bits in the same time slot, you can't actually evaluate delays like this.